# dot: dash in name

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is it possible to have a dash in the node name? I tried escaping with backslash (searching the web didn't helped either).
Example:

```
digraph test {
    some-name -> other-name;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just include the node names in double quotes like this:

```
digraph test {
    "some-name" -> "other-name";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I faced the problem, the same goes for subgraphes names:

```
digraph G {
    {node "A-1"}
    {node "B"}
    subgraph "A-1B" {edge [dir=none]"A-1" -> "B"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use identifier-like names (i.e. without spaces, dashes, etc.), but also provide a better name as a `label` attribute, by declaring node explicitly first.

```
digraph D {
  nodeA [label="Node A"];
  nodeB [label="Node B"];
  nodeA -> nodeB;
}
```